# Python : Get unique combinations from three seperate lists appended to a single list?

Tags: python, list

I have three lists with values,

```
        first_lst = ['a','b','c','d']
        second_lst = ['i','j','k']
        third_lst = ['x','y']
```

I'm trying to get unique combinations for all three lists append to a list.

Resultant Output:

```
  output = [['a','j','y'],['d','k','x'],............['d','k','y']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.product` from the standard library does that:

```
import itertools
output = [list(item) for item in itertools.product(first_lst, second_lst, third_lst)]
```

Comment: nice and clean answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if I understand this correctly, you want the lists to turn into a list of all combinations between the lists, like so: `[1, 2]` and `[3, 4]` turn into `[[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]`

one way to do this is just a loop of loops:

```
first_lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
second_lst = ['i', 'j', 'k']
third_lst = ['x', 'y']
new_lst = []

for x in first_lst:
    for y in second_lst:
        for z in third_lst:

            new_lst.append([x, y, z])

print(new_lst)
```

prints:

```
[['a', 'i', 'x'], ['a', 'i', 'y'], ['a', 'j', 'x'], ['a', 'j', 'y'], ['a', 'k', 'x'], ['a', 'k', 'y'], ['b', 'i', 'x'], ['b', 'i', 'y'], ['b', 'j', 'x'], ['b', 'j', 'y'], ['b', 'k', 'x'], ['b', 'k', 'y'], ['c', 'i', 'x'], ['c', 'i', 'y'], ['c', 'j', 'x'], ['c', 'j', 'y'], ['c', 'k', 'x'], ['c', 'k', 'y'], ['d', 'i', 'x'], ['d', 'i', 'y'], ['d', 'j', 'x'], ['d', 'j', 'y'], ['d', 'k', 'x'], ['d', 'k', 'y']]
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `zip()` function that iterates multiple iterable items like list, tuple, dictionary in python.

```
first_lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
second_lst = ['i', 'j', 'k']
third_lst = ['x', 'y']
output = []
for f, s, t in zip(first_lst, second_lst, third_lst):
    output.append([f, s, t])
print(output)
```

Comment: This won't work : only two combinations will be created.